# Unwanted gradient on site's header

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am brand new to Wordpress and Elementor, thus still learning the development proccess behind such softwares. I was given a site for optimization, and one of the issues is that there's an automatic blue gradient going behind the logo in the site's header, even though I don't see ANYWHERE at all that tells it to have such gradient. Part of the header is blue, but the left-side should be all white with just the logo. Here's an image of what's going on:

[image]

If you were in my place, where would you look first in order to figure out what's causing this? Could it be the chosen theme?

I have checked the logo's image file itself, have checked for extra CSS inspecting the site with chrome, have checked color setted on site settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check Elementor's header, and then click the logo's layer, and check the background of each of the containers, working your way up from the logo's layer. Looks like it's a background on the top most layer of the header site part.

https://elementor.com/help/header-site-part/